# Interpolate the missing 2d coordinates python

Tags: python, interpolation

I have a robot with red and green led (red in front and green in back) moving in an environment. Using position tracking scripts, I am able to fetch the coordinates related to Red and Green Led but there are instances where I miss green LED position between certain frames. 
How can I interpolate between frames to account for missing coordinate points.

Here is an example (-1 indicates not tracked):

```
red_x, red_y, green_x, green_y

420,218,428,226
-1, -1, -1, -1
-1, -1, -1, -1
-1, -1, -1, -1
421,220,428,228
-1, -1, -1, -1
422,220,429,227
```

Comment: You can just linearly interpolate the values. Subtract the two values between the untracked ones (421-420 = 1) and then divide it by the number of untracked values in between + 1 (1/(3+1) = 0.25). Then for each untracked value, add this constant multiplied with a counter (420 + 0.25, 420 + 0.25*2, 420 + 0.25*3 which becomes 420.25, 420.5, 420.75). Do this for all 4 values.

Comment: yeah but wouldn't that lead to wrong information say wrong direction of heading. I am just thinking out loud, i might be wrong though.

Comment: Not actually. Lets say you have two points 'a' and 'b' and lots of untracked points in between. Then the robot must have moved through all those intermediate points when it reaches the point 'b'. So any value that you obtain by such an interpolation would be a point in its trajectory. I'm assuming that your motion is regular and not completely random

Comment: What if the motion is irregular and random? what technique do we use generally?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your robot does or what your hardware restrictions are so I won't be able to suggest anything specific. You can use a higher sampling frequency to account for more irregularity. If you are not bent on using LEDs (I'm assuming it's for tracking), you can maybe use something like wheel encoders (infra red encoders should provide you with accurate data which you can use)